# oauth_problem=token_rejected when refreshing Yahoo's OAuth Access Token

Tags: c#, oauth, yahoo-api

I've done Oauth with Hammock, I succeed to get access token, access token secret and session handle but now I must get the [refresh access token](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-refreshaccesstoken.html) when the token expired.

I've followed the instruction and I tried to pass the access token with urldecode and without urldecode but I can't get the token, I obtain

> oauth_problem=token_rejected

UPDATE:

that's my code:

> ```
>             ##the call##
>             var AccessTokenQuery = OAuthUtil.GetAccessTokenQueryRenewal(accessToken, session_handle, accessTokenSecret);
>             AccessTokenQuery.RequestAsync(AppSettings.AccessTokenUri, null);
>             AccessTokenQuery.QueryResponse += new EventHandler<WebQueryResponseEventArgs>(AccessTokenQuery_QueryResponse);
> ```

```
     internal static OAuthWebQuery GetAccessTokenQueryRenewal(string oauth_token,string session_handle, string oauth_token_secret)               
    {
        var oauth = new OAuthWorkflow
        {
            AccessTokenUrl = AppSettings.AccessTokenUri,
            ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
            SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,         
            ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
            TokenSecret = oauth_token_secret,
            Token = oauth_token,               
            SessionHandle = session_handle,
            Version = AppSettings.oAuthVersion
        };
        var info = oauth.BuildAccessTokenInfo(WebMethod.Post);
        var objOAuthWebQuery = new OAuthWebQuery(info, false);           
        objOAuthWebQuery.HasElevatedPermissions = true;
        objOAuthWebQuery.SilverlightUserAgentHeader = "Hammock";
        return objOAuthWebQuery;
    }

 void AccessTokenQuery_QueryResponse(object sender, WebQueryResponseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Response);
            string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var parameters = MainUtil.GetQueryParameters(strResponse);
            accessToken = parameters["oauth_token"];
            accessTokenSecret = parameters["oauth_token_secret"];
            session_handle = parameters["oauth_session_handle"];

            MainUtil.SetKeyValue<string>("AccessToken", accessToken);
            MainUtil.SetKeyValue<string>("AccessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret);
            MainUtil.SetKeyValue<string>("SessionHandle", session_handle);


            userLoggedIn();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: i've edited with code!

Comment: Have you got a solution? If so, why not posting it here to help others with same problem?

Comment: Hi Marco, i don't found a solution... i've tried some way for obtain the "refresh access token" without result! Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Quick possibility you could try: you said you 'tried to pass the access token with urldecode'. Have you tried using urlencode? Urldecode is used for decoding urls returned from a web call, encoding is what is done before passing to a web call.

Also, note that the encoding scheme for Oauth is slightly different than the one used in .NET 's default encoding. You can easily write your own encoding routine though, check out the oauth spec for details.

Ex:

```
    private string UrlEncode(string value)
    {
        string unreserved = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char symbol in value)
        {
            if (unreserved.IndexOf(symbol) != -1)
                result.Append(symbol);
            else
                result.Append('%' + String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)symbol));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```